# Working with VLANS

Tags: networking, router, routing, vlan, dmz

So I recently bought a HP ProCurve (managed) switch to start messing around with VLAN's in a lab environment at home. I have a basic VLAN configured, two machines connected to the VLAN on 192.168.1.10 and 11 respectively. The The VLAN itself is sitting on 192.168.1.2.

This is great, I can speak to the VLAN (on .2) and each of the clients on the VLAN can speak to one another. The next stage is to get these machines on the Internet, and this is where I'm stuck!

My home LAN is on 192.168.0.1/24 with a fairly bulk standard router (Netgear DG834G) on 192.168.0.1.

Any tips/advices on where I go next in order to get the routing in place would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reach the Internet from either of your two PC's because they are on a different network (192.168.1/24 - I assume) than the LAN interface of your router (on 192.168.0/24) offering visbility to the Internet (your "gateway").

In order to cross networks, you need a router or a device capable of routing.

You didn't specify which ProCurve switch model you are using, but I am going to assume it's an older/standard layer 2 switch which does not do routing (a "layer 3" switch).

You'll need to either:

- Get a different router (than the DG834G) with the ability to configure and place one LAN interface in each network. i.e. An interface in each of your two networks (192.168.0 and 192.168.1).
- Place your Netgear router into the VLAN and configure the router's LAN interface to use the 192.168.0/24 network.
- Reconfigure your VLAN to use the 192.168.1/24 network and place the Netgear LAN interface onto your VLAN.

An analogy of what you're facing. Your PC's are one road - Call it Main Street.  Your router is on 1st Avenue. To get to the freeway and the rest of the world, you need to drive your car from Main Street to 1st Avenue and then onto the freeway (information superhighway!).

To complicate things, cars on Main Street only have maps of Main Street. Similarly, cars on 1st Ave only have maps off 1st Avenue.  If you went from Main Street to 1st Ave, you'd get lost cause you don't have a map.

So to drive your car Main to 1st, you'll need to get a new map as you cross from one road to another.  In very generic terms, that's the job of the router. It tells cars how to get from place to another.

Your PC's don't know how to get to the 192.168.0/24 network and won't without something - a router - telling them how to get there.

Comment: Hi John - it's a 2424M (simply bought off eBay)

Comment: Your first bullet point - could you expand slightly. Do you mean plug my router directly into one of the VLAN ports?

Comment: @TheD: Thanks for the model number. I've been looking at its instruction manual, and it is not capable of Layer 3 routing/switching. In other words, in your current topology, it does not offer a solution for your routing needs.  (For those who reading along: It is IGMP aware.)

Comment: @TheD Unfortunately - no, not with the router you are using now. I'll edit my first bullet to be more clear. The Netgear router (the DG834G) does not offer two LAN interfaces with the ability to be in two separate networks.  I was trying to say you would need a router capable of doing that.

Comment: OpenWrt Attitude Adjustment is capable of routing for multiple VLANs, but getting that up and running is a whole separate set of questions.

Comment: @John - could you recommend any routers (with the two LAN interfaces)? I'll have a look now myself but any advice is appreciated.